# Android: how to open a ListPreference dialog from outside PreferenceActivity/PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencefragment

I've created a settings menu for my app based on `PreferenceFragment`, and would like to access the settings dialog(s) from elsewhere in the app without having to open the settings menu.

My settings menu has this:

[image: settings menu]

and I want to show the same dialog when I click this menu item from the main activity:

[image: main activity]

The main `Activity` has one `ListFragment` which is where all of the UI handling code is. Neither is a `PreferenceActivity` or `PreferenceFragment`.

I just want to invoke the same `PreferenceFragment` object to get to the dialog, otherwise I'd have to write custom code to handle the preference changes manually, which I'd like to avoid.

I thought adding the `PreferenceFragment` to the `FragmentManager` in the main `Activity` would properly instantiate it, but it doesn't seem to work.

From my menu handler code for the "Sort" option:

```
    SettingsFragment fragment = (SettingsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SettingsActivity.FRAGMENT_TAG);

    // first run case
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance(getActivity());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, SettingsActivity.FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
    } 

    CustomListPreference listPref = (CustomListPreference) fragment.findPreference(SettingsFragment.KEY_PREF_SORTORDER);
    listPref.show(); // invokes showDialog(null)
```

This crashes with a `NullPointerException` on `listPref`, which shows the `PreferenceFragment` was not properly initialized.

Is there any way to achieve this effect, or do I have to write the functionality as an AlertDialog and manually handle the Preference changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to write this functionality yourself outside of the Preference classes.

> Preference, PreferenceActivity, and PreferenceFragment were all
>   designed to work together to provide a consistent UIX for android
>   apps. As such it's recommended to use them together as they were
>   intended.
>
> You can't directly replicate the UI of PreferenceActivity or
>   PreferenceFragment outside of those two classes in a regular activity
>   because the UI is built from Preference objects, not View objects like
>   regular Activities. So if you want that particular UI you'd have to
>   try and duplicate it using custom Views.
>
> https://discussions.udacity.com/t/way-to-do-listpreference-outside-of-settings-menu/45473